# Create an array according to index in another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
X= [[1,2,3],
    [3,2,1],
    [2,1,3]]
```

Now I want to create another array Y. The elements in Y should take value 1 at positions where elements in X equal 2, otherwise they should take value 0. In this example, Y should equal to

```
Y=[[0,1,0],
   [0,1,0],
   [1,0,0]]
```

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be greatly facilitated (and sped up) by using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

Y = (np.array(X) == 2).astype(int)

>>> Y
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension like this:

```
Y = [[int(i == 2) for i in l] for l in X]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, though a bit slow compared with using the numpy module.

Answer (score 3):

```
Y = [[1 if i==2 else 0 for i in row] for row in X]
```

Comment: You have it backwards

Comment: Should be `1 if ... else 0`

Comment: Yes, sorry I had the numbers backwards. Thanks for the reminder.